# Spring3.1.x とJava8の関係について

Tags: java, spring

ネットで調べてみてもSpring3.xはJava8をサポートしていなくてSpring4．xにアップグレードするようにとありましたが、試しにSpring3.1.xをJava8でコンパイルしてTomcat(JREは8)で動かしたところ問題なく動作しました。

Springの使用といっても`org.springframework.web.struts`、`org.springframework.web`しか利用していないので
問題なしと判断してもいいものなんでしょうか？

**構成**
Struts1.x + Spring3.1.0
(Springの機能はDIの部分でしか利用はしていません。)
(しかも`org.springframework.web.struts.DelegatingActionProxy`しか使ってません)

変な構成だとは思いますが、ご教授のほどよろしくおねがいします。

（何度も編集をかけてすみません。）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[このページ](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/21/spring-framework-4-0-m1-3-2-3-available/)を見ると、バージョン3.2.3から部分的にJava 8をサポートしたと書いてあります。なので、Spring3.1.xでは、Java 8がサポートされていせん。

ただし、「Java 8をサポートした」というのは、Springの開発チームがJava 8でビルド、実行した際に、問題がないことを十分に確認（テスト）した（問題があればそれを修正した）ということなので、部分的には修正無しでもJava 8で動作していた可能性はあります。

そういうことなので、問題無いかどうかは、ご自身で十分にテストするか、またはJava 8対応の修正が`org.springframework.web.struts`と`org.springframework.web`に入っていないことをソースコードの履歴から確認することで判断できると思います。

Comment: 3.1.x系を利用し続ける場合は、テストor3.2.3以降のソース変更確認が必要ということですね・・・。それであれば3.2.x系にバージョンを上げるほうがいい気がしてきました。(もちろん動作確認はします)　ありがとうございます！

Comment: バージョン3.2.3から**部分的**にJava 8をサポートしたので、3.2.3で`org.springframework.web.struts`と`org.springframework.web`がJava 8に対応しているかは分かりません（調べてみないと）。

Comment: 3.2.3を入れれば問題なし！と言い切れることはないということですね・・・。どちらにせよ、3.2.3にバージョンを上げて動作確認をしたいと思います。(お付き合いくださってありがとうございます)